# Перенос кода из php в c++

Tags: php, c++

Требуется преобразовать код php в код на с++. Особых проблем нет, кроме одного момента, в c++ оператор точки занят и не перегружается. Встает вопрос, как заменить этот оператор, так чтобы это выглядело более-менее вменяемо. Первый, приходящий в голову вариант $a.add($b.add($c)); не вызывает у меня восторга.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Языки, немного родственные, но сильно разные. Зачем это нужно, в вопросе не сказано. Если для ускорения работы, то, возможно, имеет смысл просмотреть на hiphop http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP

Comment: Раз в пару лет я пишу свой язык программирования, сильно напоминающий php. В этом году я хочу сделать не только интерпретацию, но и компиляцию, через генерацию c++ кода. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: @mikelsv, напишите явно, какой код с PHP Вы хотите перевести.



$a.add($b.add($c)) говорит, что скорее $a + $b + $c - здесь не ".", а "+" перегружать нужно

Comment: Ок, я хочу перенести $a+$b.$c;

Comment: @mikelsv, вроде перед после . в PHP $ не нужен?

Comment: . - да, не переопределить. Но, кстати, Вам вообще какая разница, насколько полученный С++-код будет похож на исходный если он нужен только чтобы его запустить? Лишь бы отлаживать было проще. Сделайте a + b.get("c") или даже a.add(b.get("c")). Или в классы поля помещайте - class B { public: T c; } - будет a+b.c

Comment: @mikelsv а чем Вас не устраивают разработки других? Тот же hiphop например? Или это работа из серии "хочу сделать сам", несмотря на то, что практического результата заведомо не будет?

Comment: @Михаил М,$ обозначает переменную и к точке никак не относится.
Я задался целью генерить вменяемый код, который возможно даже можно будет писать руками.

@alexlz, я беру, разрабатываю и не задаюсь вопросом других проектов. Это что-то вроде личного творчества. И почему же не будет практического результата?

Comment: @mikelsv это философский вопрос. Что именно Вы назовёте практическим результатом? Не знаю, как ситуация с hiphop, но подозреваю, что далеко не все php-программы можно с его помощью транслировать в лоб. А труда на его создание потрачено намного больше, чем Вы можете себе позволить.

Comment: @alexlz, если человек пишет что-то новое (или повторяет уже готовые решения), то это само по себе очень хорошо. 

Независимо от практического результата (в смысле количества пользователей этого конкретного продукта).

В любом случае при самостоятельной разработке уровень программиста растет и не в этой, так в следующей программе он сможет сделать что-то нетривиальное, в отличии от миллионов, которые только и ищут уже готовые решения.

Comment: @avp так я разве против? Тренинг -- дело святое, а охота -- пуще неволи. Только вот ждать конкретных результатов от этой работы не стоит.

Comment: @alexlz, хм, я не вижу особых сложностей из-за которых не получится транслировать php в с++. Это не сильно сложный процесс и уже как пару дней у меня есть код, который остается только доработать. Сложностей нет, поэтому я его отложил и копаюсь с amf. Ну и жду вдохновения, чтобы написать красивый код, а то началась корявость. Продолжу заниматься - будет результат.

@avp, так и есть. Самостоятельная разработка позволяет прокачаться. С одной стороны получаются жуткие велосипеды, а с другой - каждый раз они становятся лучше. ))

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о конкатенации строк то моногое зависит от типа если тип std::string то оператора + вполне достаточно,

```
std::string str1 = "Hello ";
std::string str2 = "world";

std::string str3 = str1 + str2;
```

но если вы исползуете тип  char* то придется пошаманить с присоединеним и ваш вариант вполне приемлимое решение.

Comment: Но тогда тут возникает вопрос, а что же делать с сложением чисел. Проблема не сложить две строки, а найти, чем заменить использование точки.
Хранить строки в char*? Не в этом веке. )

Comment: @mikelsv, IMHO с таким взглядом на вещи существенного выигрыша от замены интерпретации компиляцией Вы не получите.

Comment: ну если вопрос только в этом перегрузите что то врядли вам понадобится, например ~ ,не думаю что для типа std::string вам понадобится побитовая инверсия.

Comment: @Vahan Av, ох нихрена себе. В студии можно сделать opeator°. Это просто идеальное решение, то, что я искал. Мне казалось можно перегружать только определенные операторы. Но в g++ это не компилируется, а нужно именно в нем. Как сделать, чтобы оно работало в g++?

Comment: @mikelsv, насколько я помню С++, Вы правы. 

Новые символы для операций вводить нельзя.

Comment: Да точно был не прав. 
Запрещено определять свои операторы (возможны проблемы с определением приоритетов. Всетаки наверно лучше использовать метод класса.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что я все же остановлюсь на варианте, когда $a.$b будет $a.p()+$b; Функция p() будет возвращать переменную нового класса с перегруженным оператором+, который будет воспринимать + как сложение строк. На мой взгляд это самое читаемое решение и не требует лишний логики на расчет вложенности, как в $a.add($b.add($c)); Хотя может быть выбран последний вариант, если он окажется быстрее. Или возможен оптимизированный вариант $a.$b.$c -> A::add($a, $b, $c); А скорее более вероятен, если он окажется шустрее.